# SSRS group footer or header page breaks-- can they be conditional based on remaining page space?

Tags: reporting-services

I don't believe this is possible, but....

I'm using SSRS 2005 and the client wants to have a page break on a data group only if that grouping and its data can't fit on a single page.

For instance, say I was grouping on last name, and the page looked like this:

```
----------------page break---------------------
Last Name: Richards
    James
    Tyler
Last Name: Smith
    Albert
    Benjamin
    Harold
---------------page break---------------------
```

In this case, both groupings can fit on the same page.  But if the "Smith" group couldn't fit along with "Richards" on a single page, a page break would be inserted before the "Smith" group.

Is this possible in SSRS 2005?